# What is the best way to implement dual (server side) rendering with MarionetteJs?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I can I implement following workflow with MarionetteJs:

1. User opens site by URL
2. Server generates HTML + JSON data
3. MarionetteJs reads JSON data and "attaches" to generated HTML. So it doesn't rerender templates.
4. User do something -> MarionetteJs updates DOM, sends server requests, etc

So the main problem for me is 3 - attach point. What is the best way to implement dual rendering with MarionetteJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that hasn't been baked in to Marionette, yet. I've seen a number of other people solve this for Backbone in general, and it might be easy enough to take their solutions in to account.

Hopefully someone will have an answer for you, though. I'd love to see an add-on or plugin, or pull request to the project for this.